# I want to be able to say array('cat'=>'Current category ID') How do I do this?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, categories

So I'm making a wordpress theme and I'm styling archive.php
I hope one of you guys can help me with my problem.
I'm very new to all of this, so the more thorough the answer is, the better.
I'm currently using this:

```
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( array('posts_per_page'=>1, 'cat'=>'current_page_category')); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get current category ID like this:

More on this read on [WP Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category)

```
<?php 

$current = get_category(get_query_var('cat'));
$current_id = $current->term_id;

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'cat' => $current_id,
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);

?>
```